# Why doesn't CSS box-shadow work in browse?

Tags: css, webpack

Shadow box-shadow: 0px -183px 50px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset; does not work and does not appear. I attached a screenshot showing where the shadow should be

HTML:

```
<section className={`game-card size_${size}`}>
            <img className='game-card__background' src={planetOfLanaBG} alt="background-card"/>
            <div className='game-card__footer'>
                <div className='game-card__info'>
                    <span className='game-card__name'>Planet  of Lana</span>
                    <ul className='game-card__tags'>
                        { 
                            ['Adventure', 'Puzzle', 'Platformer'].map((text) => 
                            <li className='tags__tag'><Badge size={size}>{text}</Badge></li>    
                        )}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <strong className='game-card__price'>Rp 165 999</strong>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS:

```
.game-card {    
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 53.5%;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 0px -183px 50px -35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
}

.game-card__background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

I think the problem is positioning. Because when I remove the picture, a shadow appears

Comment: If this is going to be a slider, that's why I can't set the image via CSS

Comment: It would help if your HTML was HTML and not JSX, and if you used the live demo feature (behind the `<>` button) of the question editor.

Comment: "I attached a screenshot showing where the shadow should be" — No, you didn't.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:webpack]? It doesn't seem to be relevant.

Comment: Please try to change overflow in ```.game-card``` to ```overflow: visible;``` and change the ```box-shadow``` to a positive offsets ```box-shadow: 0px 183px 50px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;```.

Answer (score 1):

Please show background image in section and remove image tag. It will work. Good luck

```js
<section style={{backgroundImage: `url(${planetOfLanaBG})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}} ...>

{/* <img className='game-card__background' src={planetOfLanaBG} alt="background-card"/> */} ===> remove
```